# HTML form validation in Apps Script

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation, google-apps-script

I am very new to coding and have managed (with some help from friends) to create a form that geo-locates the submitter and writes the values (+coordinate) to a Google Sheet.  Where I am having trouble is in the `HTML5` `REGEX` and required validations.

When I click the submit button the `REGEX` and required validation pop-up windows kick in but unfortunately at the same time, the form data is submitted to the Google Sheet and the data is cleared from the form.

I cannot figure out how to make the validation happen first, and then proceed with the submission instead of both happening simultaneously.

Thank you in advance for your help!

### code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test").evaluate()
      .setTitle('Engagement Card')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return html;  
}

function addData(data){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1g*********************OnE').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ss.appendRow(data);
}
```

### test.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="formdiv">
    <table width="500">
  <tr>
    <td align=center>
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/5PX_VkGEwpy6YfE9mOBP3tSZ-PE6QW_J2AIIGRYtKuA=w231-h207-p-no" alt="" width='200' />
    </td>
    <td colspan=2 align=center>
        <font size=7>Virtual<br><br>Engagement<br><br>Card *Beta*</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="500">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3 align=center>
        <font size=3>Please complete the information below</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form id="form">
<table width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" pattern="^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$" id="first" placeholder="Please type your first name" title="Name must start with a capital letter and not contain punctuation or spaces" required="required" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 align=center><button type="submit" class="action" id="submit">Submit</button></td>
  </tr>    
</table>
</form>

</div>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function getLocation() {//when the submit button is clicked run this function (getLocation)
    if (navigator.geolocation) {//if the browser supports geolocation then...
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getData);//get the current position and pass the values to function getData
    } else {//if the browser does not support geolocation then...
        $('#formdiv').append("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");//append this message in the web interface
    }
});

function getData(position) {//starts the getData function and names data passed to it by getLocation as "position"
    console.log(position);//logs the data passed by getLocation in the JS log for viewing
    console.log('Running getData');//logs the words "Running getData" in the JS log
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;//assigns the latitude value from geolocation to var latitude
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;//assigns the longitude value from geolocation to var longitude
    var coords = [latitude, longitude];//combines latitude and longitude into an array named var coords
    var data1 = $('#first').val();//gets the values from the inputs using the input id

    var data = [data1,latitude,longitude];//combines data elements in an array named var data


   console.log(data);//logs the data values in the JS log for viewing

   google.script.run.addData(data);//runs the function in the code.gs file

   console.log('Data transmitted');//logs the words "Data transmitted" in the JS log

        var field1= document.getElementById('first');            

        field1.value= field1.defaultValue;

};



</script>
```

UPDATE 20DEC 1430EST: I changed getLocation to run on submit (vs. on click) using @user9090's advice and added some console logs.  Changing to .submit allows the validation and required fields to do their job which is what I was looking for.  However, now the script stops in getLocation.  "browser supports geolocation" gets logged in the console but then the screen goes white.  I believe that getData is not being ran anymore.  Any ideas?

```
$('#form').submit(function getLocation() {//when the submit button is clicked run this function (getLocation)
    console.log('getting location');
    if (navigator.geolocation) {//if the browser supports geolocation then...
    console.log('browser supports geolocation');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getData);//get the current position and pass the values to function getData
    } else {//if the browser does not support geolocation then...
    console.log('browser does not support geolocation');
        $('#formdiv').append("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");//append this message in the web interface
    }
});

function getData(position) {//starts the getData function and names data passed to it by getLocation as "position"
    console.log(position);//logs the data passed by getLocation in the JS log for viewing
    console.log('Running getData');//logs the words "Running getData" in the JS log
```

Update 20DEC 1620EST: **Turns out, the script works fine now, and validates.  My last comment is only true is there is a validation error.**  If I complete the form abiding by the regex and required elements, the data submits just fine.  Although, if I have a validation error, the script hangs in getLocation after the error is corrected and the submit button is pressed again...

Answer (score 1):

Change first 7 lines inside your script block (in test.html) with following lines of code,

```
 $("#form").submit(function(event) {
  console.log("Submitting form....");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(e){

  // Do you validation here

  }).addData(this);  // this is a form's data passed to your GAS function
 });
```

Comment: thanks, I am curious, what abiut the location information?  If I change the first 7 lines (which get the user's location) to this dont I lose that?

Comment: This is just an example how you can do it. But, your edited code should work as per your requirement, I don't understand why is it not working for you? It is working for me.

Comment: so when you use the code, and purposefully leave a field blank to trip the validation, when you go back and complete the field (after the validation occurs) the data still submits to the sheet?

Comment: I still cannot get it past "browser supports geolocation" in the console log if I correct a validation error and resubmit.  Script works just fine if there are no initial validation errors.

Comment: I figured out what is happening...  The prompt that asks the user to allow/disallow their location is appearing for a split second and then disappearing.  Never allowing the user to complete the authorization.  Any thoughts?